# Application.Current.Exit() and OnSuspendingEvent

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

In Universal Windows 10 C#/Xaml Application when I close my app via Alt+F4 `OnSuspending` event is fired. Although, when I call `Application.Current.Exit()` this is not the case, despite the documentation states that this event is fired whenever app is about to be terminated.

Why is this the case? It looks like inconsistent behaviour which caused bug in my app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This official graphic by Microsoft illustrates the application lifecycle for a Windows Universal Platform app:

[image: Lifecycle]

The [documentation of this lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt243287.aspx) explains:

> After an app has been closed by the user, it's **first suspended** and **then terminated**, and enters the **NotRunning** state.

Further more, Microsoft recommends to **NOT** close the app programatically!
From ["Guidelines for app suspend and resume"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx):

> Don't include Close buttons or offer users other ways to terminate your app in its UI. Users should feel confident that the system is managing their apps for them. The system can terminate apps automatically to ensure the best system performance and reliability, and users can choose to close apps using gestures on Windows or through the Task Switcher on Windows Phone.

But if you...

> close an app programmatically, the system treats it as an app crash.

Therefore, your app will go from a *Running* state, directly into a *NotRunning* state.

You might be able to observe this behavior if you 
handle the `Exiting` event of the [`CoreApplication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.aspx) class.

Answer (score 4):

1. Microsoft [does not recommend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.exit.aspx) to exit application from code:

> Use this method to provide UI that enables users to exit your app. Normally, however, you should not provide this UI because the system automatically manages app lifetime and terminates suspended apps as needed to free resources.

2. Application.Exit does not suspend application, but shutdown it - that's why your code in OnSusspending is not called
3. Workaround: in your App.cs add

a) `using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;`

b) in App constructor add `CoreApplication.Exiting += CoreApplication_Exiting;`

c) write CoreApplication_Exiting method

```
private void CoreApplication_Exiting(object sender, object e)
        {
            //HERE your code
        }
```

it will run all time when application terminates.

Answer (score 1):

The `OnSuspending` is called when the app will be suspended. It has nothing to do with termination. The docu states that when the user closes the application with alt+f4 it is also called…but this is just a nice thing. 
For Termination there is no event fired. This is why you should save the states at suspension.

For example if the application crashes the `OnSuspending` is also not called.

If you look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.exit
It says

> “Normally, however, you should not provide this UI because the system
>   automatically manages app lifetime and terminates suspended apps as
>   needed to free resources”

Meaning the `OnSuspend` is not called when you terminate your app with this method.

To handle the difference between Case1: Suspending->Terminating by the system (e.g. when your app is minimized and not used after that) or Closed by Alt+F4 and Case2: the app crashes or is terminated by `Application.Current.Exit()` use the `PreviousExecutionState` on the `LaunchActivatedEventArgs` in the `OnLaunched` method (or `IActivatedEventArgs` on the `OnActivated` if you use that).

Here are the possible values: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.activation.applicationexecutionstate.aspx